# Insert archive loop insert another page

Tags: php

I have archive.php in my content management system which allows to search for articles like `mywebsite.com/archive?s=test`. Now i tried to show this posts of the search query in another page of my page. Like `<?php insert('archive.php?s=test'); ?>` .

I am not an expert on PHP coding. But maybe you can show me a way how i could import this post of a search query with archive.php loop. Or tell me that this is not possible :-) Thank you.

This is the code my archive page.

```
  <?php if (!$t['page_heading']) : ?>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if (has_items($t['latest_posts'])) : ?> 
            <div class="row">
                <?php foreach ($t['latest_posts'] as $t['loop']) : ?>
                    <div class="col-12 mb-3">
                        <?php insert('partials/loop.php'); ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div> </div> </div>

            <?= $t['pagination_html']; ?>
        <?php else : ?>
                <?php
                insert(
                    'partials/empty.php',
                    [
                        'empty_message' => __('nothing-found-archive', _T)
                    ]
                );
                ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
```

This is the loop.php

```
 <?= e(limit_string($t['loop.post_title'], 65), false); ?>
        </h3></a>

        <div class="post-footer text-muted">
             <div id="hidden-xs"> <?= e(limit_string($t['loop.post_excerpt'], 145), false); ?></div>
                <div class="mb-1 mt-1"> <span class="badge badge-cat"><i class="fas fa-newspaper"></i> <?= e_attr($t['loop.feed_name']) ?></span> <span class="badge badge-cat"><i class="far fa-folder-open"></i> <?= e_attr($t['loop.category_name']) ?></span> 
                <span class="badge badge-cat"><i class="far fa-clock"></i> vor <?= time_ago($t['loop.post_pubdate'], _T); ?></span>
```

search function

```
public function archive()
    {
        $app = app();
        $postModel = new PostModel;
        $feedModel = new FeedModel;
        $engineModel = new EngineModel;
        $categoryModel = new CategoryModel;

        $data = [
            'title' => __('archive', _T),
            'meta.description' => __('archive-description', _T),
            'body_class' => 'archive',
            'searching_site' => false,
            'by_feed' => false,
        ];

        $query = sp_strip_tags(trim($app->request->get('s')), true);
        $feedID  = (int) $app->request->get('feed', 0);


        $feedsTable = $feedModel->getTable();
        $postsTable = $postModel->getTable();

        $categoriesTable = $categoryModel->getTable();

        // Current page number
        $currentPage = (int) $app->request->get('page', 1);

        $filters['sort'] = 'post-publish-date';

        if (mb_strlen($query) > 3) {
            $filters['where'][] = ["{$postsTable}.post_title", 'LIKE', "%$query%"];
            $filters['where'][] = ["{$postsTable}.post_content", 'LIKE', "%$query%", 'OR'];

            $data['site_search_query'] = $query;
            $data['searching_site'] = true;

            $data['page_heading'] = sprintf(__('search-results-for', _T), $query);
            $data['title'] = sprintf(__('search-results-for-title', _T), $query);
            $data['meta.description'] = sprintf(__('search-results-for-desc', _T), $query);
            $data['body_class'] .= ' search-results';
        }

        if ($feedID) {
            $feed = $feedModel->read($feedID, ['feed_id', 'feed_name']);
            if ($feed) {
                $filters['where'][] = ["{$postsTable}.post_feed_id", '=', $feed['feed_id']];
                $data['by_feed'] = true;
                $data['feed'] = $feed;
                $data['title'] = $feed['feed_name'];
                $data['page_heading'] = $feed['feed_name'];
            }
        }

        $itemsPerPage = (int) get_option('latest_posts_count', 10);

        // Total item count
        $totalCount = $postModel->countRows(null, $filters);

        $pageQuery = [];

        if ($data['searching_site']) {
            $pageQuery['s'] = $query;
        }

        if ($data['by_feed']) {
            $pageQuery['feed'] = $feedID;
        }

        $queryStr = http_build_query($pageQuery);

        if (!empty($queryStr)) {
            $queryStr = "&{$queryStr}";
        }

        // Pagination instance
        $pagination = new Pagination($totalCount, $currentPage, $itemsPerPage);
        $pagination->setUrl("?page=@id@{$queryStr}");

        // Generated HTML
        $paginationHtml = $pagination->renderHtml();

        // Offset value based on current page
        $offset = $pagination->offset();

        // Fields to query
        $fields[] = "{$postsTable}.post_id, {$postsTable}.post_category_id, {$postsTable}.post_title, {$postsTable}.post_excerpt, {$postsTable}.post_featured_image, {$postsTable}.post_type, {$postsTable}.post_source, {$postsTable}.post_pubdate, {$postsTable}.created_at, {$postsTable}.post_hits";
        $fields[] = "{$feedsTable}.feed_name, {$feedsTable}.feed_id, {$feedsTable}.feed_logo_url";
        $fields[] = "{$categoriesTable}.category_name, {$categoriesTable}.category_slug, {$categoriesTable}.category_icon";

        // Query to fetch the users and their respective role names
        $sql = $postModel->select($fields)
        ->leftJoin(
            $feedsTable,
            "{$postsTable}.post_feed_id",
            '=',
            "{$feedsTable}.feed_id"
        )->leftJoin(
            $categoriesTable,
            "{$postsTable}.post_category_id",
            '=',
            "{$categoriesTable}.category_id"
        )->limit($itemsPerPage, $offset);

        // Apply Filters
        $sql = $postModel->applyModelFilters($sql, $filters);
        $stmt = $sql->execute();
        // List entries
        $latestPosts = $stmt->fetchAll();


        $maxSliderItems = get_option('max_slider_items', 10);
        $sliderPosts = array_slice($latestPosts, 0, $maxSliderItems);


        $engines = $engineModel->readMany(['engine_id', 'engine_name']);

        $data['default_engine']         = (int) get_option('default_engine');
        $data['engines']                = $engines;
        $data['archive_active']            = 'active';
        $data['slider_posts']           = $sliderPosts;
        $data['latest_posts']           = $latestPosts;
        $data['pagination_html']        = $paginationHtml;

        return view('archive.php', $data);
    }
```

Comment: I suppose the insert function is like an include, you cannot include a script with get parameters, since it is not a http request. So this won't work: `insert('archive.php?s=test');`.

Comment: depending on insert function you could implement `<?php insert('archive.php', ['s' => $_GET['s'] ?? '']); ?>` then use the value to then do a query, really you need to show the function else its impossible to answer

Comment: I found and added the search function. Thank you.